# when will kubernetes service supoort set-based selector?

Tags: service, kubernetes, selector, set-based

As the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) says:

> Newer resources, such as Job, Deployment, Replica Set, and Daemon Set, support set-based requirements as well.

Why does the resource *service* not support set-based requirements? When will it support that?

I want to create a *service* that select *pods* with **key** = **v1** or **v2**. How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Services belong to the `v1` API group (which is stable). By that time, the set-based selector was not implemented. In order to allow that kind of selector, they would need to create a new type of `Service` that would belong to the alpha/beta API group. In this sense, this would likely take time in order to be production ready. I did not find any information about plans on working on that. I would not expect it in the short term for this to be available.

Comment: : (    I want to get _endpoints_ by _service_ that select _pods_ with **key** = **v1** or **v2**. Is there any way to do so?